# Google Action / Dialogflow : how to ask for geolocation

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to implement a simple app for Google Assistant.
All works fine, but now I have a problem with the "permission" helper :
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#helper_intents

I have an intent connected with webhook to my java application. When an user types a sentence similar to "near to me", I want to ask to him his location and then use `lat/lon` to perform a search.

es: Brazilian restaurant near to me

1. my intent "searchRestaurant" is fired
2. I receive the webhook request and I parse it
3. if I find a parameter that is connected to a sentence like "near to me", so instead to response with a "Card" or a "List" I return a JSON that represent the helper request :

---

```
{
"conversationToken": "[]",
"expectUserResponse": true,
"expectedInputs": [
    {
        "inputPrompt": {
            "initialPrompts": [
                {
                    "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
                }
            ],
            "noInputPrompts": []
        },
        "possibileIntents": [
            {
                "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
                "inputValueData": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                    "optContext": "Posso accedere alla tua posizione?",
                    "permission": [
                        "NAME",
                        "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

but something seems to be wrong, and I receive an error:

> "{\n  \"responseMetadata\": {\n    \"status\": {\n      \"code\": 10,\n      \"message\": \"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response\",\n      \"details\": [{\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value\",\n        \"value\": \"{\\"id\\":\\"1cc45c5e-c398-4ea7-98a5-408f31ce142d\\",\\"timestamp\\":\\"2018-08-02T14:45:05.752Z\\",\\"lang\\":\\"it\\",\\"result\\":{},\\"alternateResult\\":{},\\"status\\":{\\"code\\":206,\\"errorType\\":\\"partial_content\\",\\"errorDetails\\":\\"Webhook call failed. **Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: conversationToken in message** google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.WebhookResponse.\\"},\\"sessionId\\":\\"1533221100163\\"}\"\n      }]\n    }\n  }\n}"

The "conversationToken" is filled, so I don't understand the error message.
Maybe I'm trying to perform the operation in a wrong way.

So, which is the correct way to call this helper?

--> I've created a second intent "`askGeolocation`" that have `"actions_intent_PERMISSION"` as "Event", and ... if I understand correctly the documentation, should be trigger if the request for helper is correct.

How can I get this working?

UPDATE :

I find some example of the json response for ask permission and seems that it should be different from the one above that i'm using :

https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/ActionsOnGoogle/AskForPermission.json

```
{
"payload": {
"google": {
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "systemIntent": {
    "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
    "data": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
      "optContext": "To deliver your order",
      "permissions": [
        "NAME",
        "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
      ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so, i've implemented it and now the response seems to be good (no more error on parsing it), but i still receive an error on it validation :

**UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "permission: Cannot find field."**

so, a problem still persist.
Anyone know the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After some tests i found the problem.
I was returning a wrong json repsonse with "permission" instead of "permissions":

```
"permission**s**": [
    "NAME",
    "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
]
```

So the steps to ask for location are correct. I report them here as a little tutorial in order to help who is facing on it for the first time:

1) In DialogFlow, add some logic to your Intent, in order to understand when is ok to ask to user his location. In my case, i've added a "parameter" that identify sentences like "nearby" and so on.

2) When my Intent is fired i receive to my java application a request like this :

```
...
"queryResult": {
"queryText": "ristorante argentino qui vicino",
"action": "bycategory",
"parameters": {
  "askgeolocation": "qui vicino",
  "TipoRistorante": ["ristorante", "argentino"]
},
...
```

3) If "askgeolocation" parameter is filled, instead to return a "simple message" o other type of message, i return a json for ask the permission to geolocation :

```
{
"payload": {
"google": {
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "systemIntent": {
    "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
    "data": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
      "optContext": "To deliver your order",
      "permissions": [
        "NAME",
        "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
     ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4) You MUST have a second Intent that is configured with "actions_intent_PERMISSION " event :

[image]

- No training phrases
- No Action and params
- No Responses

But with Fulfillment active :

[image]

5) Once your response arrive to Google Assistant this is the message that appear :

[image]

6) Now, if user answer "ok" you receive this json on your webhook :

```
     {
   "responseId": "32cf46cf-80d8-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "queryResult": {
     "queryText": "actions_intent_PERMISSION",
     "action": "geoposition",
     "parameters": {
     },
 "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
 "fulfillmentMessages": [{
   "text": {
     "text": [""]
   }
 }],
 "outputContexts": [{
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }, {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "parameters": {
     "PERMISSION": true
   }
 }, {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }, {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }, {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }, {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }],
 "intent": {
   "name": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "displayName": "geoposition"
 },
 "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
 "languageCode": "it"
 },
 "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
 "source": "google",
 "version": "2",
 "payload": {
   "isInSandbox": true,
   "surface": {
     "capabilities": [{
       "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
     }, {
       "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
     }, {
       "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
     }, {
       "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
     }]
   },
   "requestType": "SIMULATOR",
   "inputs": [{
     "rawInputs": [{
       "inputType": "KEYBOARD"
     }],
     "arguments": [{
       "textValue": "true",
       "name": "PERMISSION",
       "boolValue": true
     }],
     "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION"
   }],
   "user": {
     "lastSeen": "2018-08-03T08:55:20Z",
     "permissions": ["NAME", "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"],
     "profile": {
       "displayName": ".... full name of the user ...",
       "givenName": "... name ...",
       "familyName": "... surname ..."
     },
     "locale": "it-IT",
     "userId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "device": {
     "location": {
       "coordinates": {
         "latitude": 45.xxxxxx,
         "longitude": 9.xxxxxx
       }
     }
   },
   "conversation": {
     "conversationId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "type": "ACTIVE",
     "conversationToken": "[]"
   },
   "availableSurfaces": [{
     "capabilities": [{
       "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
     }, {
       "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
     }, {
       "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
     }]
   }]
     }
   },
   "session": "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
```

that contains, name/surname and latitude/longitude. This information can be saved in your application, in order to not perform again this steps.

I hope this helps.

Davide

Answer (score 2):

In your intent, you can ask for a parameter with a custom Entity. This you can do like this:

- entity you can define as "near"
- put all the synonyms for near for which you want to trigger location permission in this entity
- do not mark this parameter as "required"
- do not put any prompt
- in the training phrases, add some phrases with this parameter
- in your webhook, keep a check on the parameter, if present ask for permission if not continue.
- add a permission event to another intent
- do your post permission processing in that intent

Entity

[image]

Intent

[image]

I hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav for your answer! I've already done all the things you described. When Dialogflow calls my webhook ( fired with "near to" sentence ) i try to respond with the json above ( permission for geolocation ) but this give me an error (in Action simulator ) :  "Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: conversationToken in message", but this filed is present! I really don't undertand where is my fault :-(

Comment: Check your version for Dialogflow and Action on Google.

Comment: I'm using v2, so i think that the problem is not on a wrong version. I've updated the question ... seems that i was using a wrong json format, but i  still have an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are samples on this topic specifically that guide you through exactly what's needed for requesting permissions in [Node](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs) and [Java](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-java).

Note: There are helper intents samples available in [Node](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs) and [Java](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-java) as well.